# Can I find which values in an array do not have corresponding database records using only one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of a few values that I get from an uploaded file. I would like to identify which values in the file are *not* in my database.

I already know how to check the values one at a time by looping over the array and checking for matching records from the database for each value.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE a_column = ?');
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $stmt->execute([$value]);
    if ($stmt->fetchColumn() === '0')   // do something with $value
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to get the results in one query. If I already had the values in an SQL table, it would be easy to find which ones had matching values in another table by joining the tables and checking the results for null values in the table in question.

```sql
SELECT i.value
FROM
    imaginary_values_table i
    LEFT JOIN my_table m ON i.value = m.a_column
WHERE
    m.id IS NULL
```

Is it possible to do this type of query using a list of values instead?

I am familiar with `IN`, but I don't see how it could be used for this directly, because I am trying to find which items *in an array* are not in a table. With `IN` I could get all the rows from the table that are in my array, or with `NOT IN` I could get all the rows that are not in my array.

Comment: Do you upload the file using e.g phpmyadmin or have you made your own insert query from the website?

Comment: How about something like `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE a_column IN (".join(", ", $values).")"`. Using the [MySQL IN Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) and the [join function.](http://php.net/function.join)

Comment: I just inadvertently discovered while editing this and looking for alternate solutions that it was already a duplicate when I asked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.val
FROM (SELECT 1 AS val
      UNION
      SELECT 2 AS val
      UNION
      SELECT 3 AS val
      ...) AS t1
LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2 ON t1.val = t2.a_column
WHERE t2.a_column IS NULL
```

You can build the `UNION` subquery from your array of values:

```
$union = implode(' UNION ', array_map(function($val) {
    return "SELECT $val AS val";
}, $array));
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! This is exactly the kind of thing I was thinking of. I'm going to experiment with it, but offhand do you think doing it this way would be more efficient than executing the prepared statement repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be. Every database call has a significant amount of overhead, even with prepared statements. Of course, how important this is will depend on how large your array is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to do this by selecting all the rows that match values in the array using `IN` and then using `array_diff` with the original array and the query result to get the ones that aren't there.

```
$qs = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($values)),',');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a_column FROM my_table WHERE a_column IN ($qs)");
$stmt->execute($values);
$not_there = array_diff($values, $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));
```